# Streamlit Python - every time new line

Tags: python, streamlit

come across Streamlit for Python. Seems to be what I want, just don't understand, how can I keep the info all the time on the same element. Now it's recreated each time when it runs.

```
import streamlit as st
import time

for x in range(10):
    st.metric(label="Temperature", value="7{} °F".format(x), delta="1.2 °F")
    time.sleep(2)
```

This is how does it look like. I want to keep just 'redraw' the same element. Not create a new one each time...

[image: how does it look like]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the st element to a variable.
In particular, you can create an empty element:

```
element = st.empty()
```

Then, modify the element:

```
for x in range(10):
    element.metric(label="Temperature", value="7{} °F".format(x), delta="1.2 °F")
    time.sleep(2)
```